# phpspec spec_path location configuration

Tags: php, phpspec

Can't figure this out and the docs are not especially helpful in this case.

I have a package structure like this:

```
-src/
  - Acme/
    - Foo/
     - Component1/
     - Component2/
     …
```

What I try to achieve is that every testsuite should be located in it's corresponding component directory.

My `phpspec.yml` (located at `./phpspec.yml`) looks like this:

```
suites:

    acme_foo_compoment1_suite:
       namespace: Acme\Foo\Component1
       src_path: src/Acme/Foo/Component1
       spec_path: src/Acme/Foo/Component1
       spec_prefix: Specs

    acme_foo_compoment2_suite:
       namespace: Acme\Foo\Component2
       src_path: src/Acme/Foo/Component2
       spec_path: src/Acme/Foo/Component2
       spec_prefix: Specs
```

This won't work as specs are created in `src/Acme/Foo/Component1/Specs/src/Acme/Foo/Component1` instead of `src/Acme/Foo/Component1/Specs`.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony2Extension](https://github.com/phpspec/Symfony2Extension) implements similar kind of setup. I don't recommend using it, as it's still not clear where it is going to go. However, you could implement your own extension based on what's done in there.